# How to get correct size for img and figcaption inside figure

Tags: html, css

I am having truble with the css for an image inside figure. This is the html:

```css
#content figure {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#content img {
  height: 180px;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
#content figcaption {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <figure>
    <img style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x300');"></img>
    <figcaption>image caption that is to long to fit</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <!--... /*Here it can be multiple figure after each other*/-->
</div>
```

What I want is that the figure should have a fixed height at 200px. The figcaption should have an automatic height depending on how many rows of text there is. The image should then take up the rest of the height and scale the width to keep the proportions. The width of the figure should therefore be the same width as the image inside it. The code I have now is not doing everything and I do not understand how I should modify it to do what I want.

Comment: You don't need a closing </img> tag. You can use it directly <img src="" />. And <img> should have a src according to W3C standards. Using background image for <img> tag seems unwanted. Why dont you use a <span> or <div> instead of <img>

Comment: The reason I am using img together with background-image is to stop people from right click and save the image. I know this does not stop anyone from actually get the image, it just makes it a Little harder.

Answer (score 1):

In your `#content figcaption` style add `word-wrap: break-word;`, set `height: auto;` and give it the same width as your image, so something like this:

```
#content figcaption {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#content figure {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#content img {
  height: 180px;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

#content figcaption {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <figure>
    <img style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z6RE.jpg?s=48&g=1');"/>
    <figcaption>image caption that is to long to fit</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <!--... /*Here it can be multiple figure after each other*/-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to dynamically adjust the height of your image to accommodate the figcaption(since your figcaption have varied height as per content).

An alternative is to use the image to use the whole figure height and add figcaption on top of the figure using position.

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/thomas014/t6vwa74b/)